# Error: Document (get by id) is not declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Someone just quit at my job and I inherited the web project he was working on.
I have little experience with asp/vb and I might be missing something obvious here, but there is my problem:

I am experiencing this strange error where I'm trying to access the elements of my aspx page with `Document.getElementByID()` in but I only get the error " 'Document' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level".

I get this error on all the pages I try to access `Document` to find the elements. There is no previous reference to "Document" in the code, so it is possible the problem has been there since the beginning but never got noticed.

I tried calling `Document` in different function/scope and the error persist. I also verified that all the pages inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`. I have no other issue with the project, the pages render correctly and I can access the elements generated by the "Code Gen File".

I was wondering if there could be some references missing to the project or if there could be anything that I haven't checked that would explain this.

Comment: it is document.getElementById not a "Document", Note javascript is case sensitive

Comment: document.getElementById (note the casing) is a JavaScript call. Are you in JavaScript or the VB code behind?

Comment: Hum, it seems like I got messed up in my thoughs... 
You see, the server-side code has "on change" listener set-up on some fields, and do some inputs validation. This is kinda frustrating since everytime one textbox looses the focus, the page do a postback. 
So I was planning to do some client-side verification to smooth things a little bit by doing some AJAX, and using the existing server-side code to do so. But the way I planned it (by passing the Id in Ajax and using it to get the element on the server) wouldn't have worked anyways now that I think of it.. thanks for the aanswer!

Comment: @UncleBen It may be worth knowing that the TextBox class has an 'AutoPostback' property which can be set to false to stop it post backing when it looses focus.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald Thanks for mentioning, would it "deactivate" the listener declared server-side, (since there would be no postback)?

Comment: @UncleBen Good question, it would depend how the listener was declared, but if it's declared server side my assumption would be yes.

Comment: Just for the record, when setting AutoPostBack to false, the server-sides listener do not get cancelled, they simply get delayed to the next post-back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById() is a client side JavaScript function.

Your aspx page is a server side web form.

You can't access client side functions in your code behind like that.

To reference server side controls (like those defined in you aspx page) you can simple use their 'id' property in the aspx

Comment: Yeah as I though it was something kinda obvious like that.. but by looking up I saw some people using this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Which seems to be what messed me up.. ..